# pre_get_posts on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

I have a custom post type which displays posts just fine on the page when I use a custom wp_query however, that breaks pagination, so I tried to use pre_get_posts instead as I'm already using that to handle pagination offsets and that works find on normal posts.

When I try to use pre_get_posts to set the post type for a particular page/post-type though, it shows a 404. I did have a custom post in there with the same string in the name as the custom post type; 'business-challenges' is the post type and 'facing-business-challenges' was the post it redirected to. Since I've deleted that post it now just shows a 404.

My pre get posts function:

```
    function query_business_challenges( $query ) {

        if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_page('business-challenges')) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'business-challenges' );
        } // end if
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_business_challenges', 1 );
```

And my Custom Post Type:

```
    function pt_business_challenges() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                => 'Business Challenges',                        
            'singular_name'       => 'Business Challenge',                         
            'menu_name'           => 'B. Challenges',                        
            'parent_item_colon'   => 'Business Challenges',                        
            'all_items'           => 'All Business Challenges',                    
            'view_item'           => 'View Business Challenge',                    
            'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Business Challenge',                 
            'add_new'             => 'Add New',
            'edit_item'           => 'Edit Business Challenge',                    
            'update_item'         => 'Update Business Challenge',                  
            'search_items'        => 'Search Business Challenges',                 
            'not_found'           => 'Not found',
            'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
        );
        $args = array(
            'label'               => 'business-challenges',                         
            'description'         => 'For New and Previous Business Challenges',   
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/business-challenges'),                  
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 7,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-chart-area',         
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'page',
        );
        register_post_type( 'business-challenges', $args );                         
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'pt_business_challenges', 0 );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pre_get_posts` does not work on page templates and static front pages. It will 404. If I read the `WP_Query` class correctly, the page ID is passed to a parameter such as `p` once the URL is parsed. You can try unsetting this parameter and check if it changes the query, but I doubt if this will be the only parameter to change to make it work. Have never played around with this, so everything is just pure speculation. This is quite an opportunity for someone to play around with `pre_get_posts` on page templates

You have to use a custom query here to output what you need. As for pagination, you need to add the following your custom query to make it work

This goes before you define your arguments

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

*Remember to change `'paged'` to `'page'` for static front pages*

You then need to set the `'paged'` parameter in your query arguments

```
'paged' => $paged,
```

It is as easy then as to pass the `$max_num_pages` property of your custom query to your pagination function.

Example

If your custom query looks like this

```
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

then you need to pass `$q->max_num_pages` to your pagination function like the following

```
next_posts_link( 'Next posts', $q->max_num_pages );
```

### EDIT

Just one or two notes on your code

- If you want to show custom post types on page templates, you need to set `has_archive` to `false`, otherwise the archive template will be used to show custom post types
- If you are talking about getting 404 errors on your custom post type **archive** template, then you just need to flush your permalinks by visiting the permalink settings page is backend. No need for any type of custom code or filters.

### EDIT 2

From your paste (*which should be an edit to your question*), you have a few small issues here

- `wp_reset_query()` is wrong. It is used with `query_posts` which you should never use. You should be using `wp_reset_postdata()`
- It seems you are trying to add your pagination on top of your query. In order for this to work, you need to define your custom query first. You can add your pagination before the loop however.
- As I said, you need to set the `$max_pages` parameter in `next_posts_link()`

Your query should look similar to this

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    //Rest of your arguments
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

/*
 * If you need your pagination above the loop,
 * this is the earliest to add it. You cannot add it above
 */
next_posts_link( 'Next Posts', $loop->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Previous Posts' );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();

        //YOUR LOOP

    } // endwhile

    // Add pagination here
    next_posts_link( 'Next Posts', $loop->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Previous Posts' );
    // Reset postdata, VERY VERY IMPORTANT
    wp_reset_postdata();
} // endif
```

Comment: I have made an edit to my post. Be sure to check it out :-)

Comment: Ah, I had no idea it didn't work on pages with custom wp queries... I've tried to do the $paged thing but it just 404's on the second page (always have trouble here, that's why I tried to keep to default query, where it works fine.). However, when I said pagination, what I really meant was `<?php echo get_next_posts_page_link(); ?>`. A link to next page of posts.

Comment: No, you should use `next_posts_link()` or `get_next_posts_link() and `previous_posts_link()` or `get_previous_posts_link()` :-)

Comment: Using `get_next_posts_link()` gives a link with no /page/2, just the current page. `get_next_posts_page_link()` does give me /page/2 but it 404's. Pagination is the main thing that holds me up every time I do a Wordpress site :/ I need to build filtering into this yet... ED: http://pastebin.com/Ww9KgsnS if it helps ED2: I tried both page and paged.

Comment: File an edit to your question with your code

Comment: I think it would be a separate question to be honest, I'll try more with getting paged to work. Marked as answered though, as it's not possible. Cheers :)

Comment: I have added an edit with how your query should look like. This setup works. If it does not work, then you have another issue somewhere. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: @Pieter Goosen Isn't there a new function for next and previous posts link?

Comment: @BradDalton yes, there are, but it doesn't work with custom queries. Note, the previous and next posts links are not depreciated, so it is still totally valid

Comment: @Pieter Goosen thank you for the reply. Unfortunately it's still not working, I did manage to get the links to show /page/2 at least. I'm sure it's very much something else I've done wrong. I will create another question if need be though. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ed: turns out it was because the slug was the same as the page name...

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted. This had me scratching my head for a second or two because I know my code works, so what else can be wrong ;-) Enjoy